# How to increase space between text and its underline within UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uilabel

I have a one-line UILabel with attributed string that has underline. Anybody know how to increase space between that text and its underline? I would think this is supposed to be a common thing to do, but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: do you have to use UILabel? If you use UITextView I know a way.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin - out of curiosity, how would you do that with UITextView?

Comment: Subclass NSLayoutManager and set it as textView's layout manager. Then override `underlineGlyphRange:underlineType:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:` and call `drawUnderlineForGlyphRange:underlineType:baselineOffset:lineFragmentRect:lineFragmentGlyphRange:containerOrigin:` with the offset that you want.

Comment: @ymotov Did you figure it out? I wanna do the same thing. Can you share your approach?

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin Can you share some example codes? Because both methods come with a lot of arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can, but you're welcome to create an UILabel subclass and drawing your own line (using UIBezierPath or CGPath, for example) at the distance of your choice using the drawRect: method on your subclass.